# Get the number of required and non required Arguments in Functions

Tags: python, function

I want to get the Number of required Arguments and non. I would be really happy if someone could help me, I am kinda stuck here.

I have tried following, I don't  know if that is the right way to go for it.

```
from inspect import signature

def Test(X, Y = 4):
print(X,Y)

R = str(signature(Test))
cu = ""
for i in R:
    if i.isalpha():
        cu = "".join([cu,i])
print(len(cu))
#Output: 2 (I would like to have something like req_Arg = 1, non_req_Arg = 1)
```

I am using py 3.0

Thank you for suggestions in advance.

Comment: can you explain in detail?

Comment: What do required arguments and non required arguments mean? How do you want to calculate them?

Comment: I mean with required Argument in a Function for Example ( def(X, Y = 4: ...), where X is required to run the function. Y wouldn't be, because it has a standard Variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the type of parameter and whether or not it has a default by iterating through `inspect.signature(Test).parameters.values()`:

```
>>> for param in inspect.signature(Test).parameters.values():
...     print(param.kind, param.default)
...
POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD <class 'inspect._empty'>
POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD 4
```

(https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/inspect.html#inspect.Parameter)

It'd be relatively trivial to translate that into the output you're looking for (leaving the exercise up to you).